# How To Make 'Reply' & 'Reply-All' Button Grey In Outlook C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, selection, office-addins

In outlook…

- If you select multiple email from top to bottom, Reply/Reply-all buttons are enabled
- If you select multiple email from bottom to top, Reply/Reply-all buttons are disabled

**CASE-1 : Selecting 'Test 2' & then select 'Test 1' => Reply/Reply-all buttons are enabled**

[image]

**CASE-2 : Selecting 'Test 1' & then select 'Test 2' => Reply/Reply-all buttons are disabled**

[image]

I have `Explorer.SelectionChange` event which checks if there are multiple emails are selected. If there are multiple emails are selected, Then I have disabled 'Reply/Reply-All' events by `MailItem.Actions["Reply"].Enabled = false;`.

```
Explorer objExplorer = (Explorer)Api.Instance.GetActiveExplorer();
if (objExplorer != null)
{
    objExplorer.SelectionChange += () =>
    {
        Selection objSelectionList = objExplorer.Selection;
        if (objSelectionList != null && objSelectionList.Count > 1 && objSelectionList[1] != null)
        {
            MailItem objMailItem = objSelectionList[1] as MailItem;
            if (objMailItem != null)
            {
                objMailItem.Actions["Reply"].Enabled = false;
                objMailItem.Actions["Reply to All"].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But it's not giving me output like **CASE-2**. So basically I want to make both buttons disabled in **CASE-1** as shown in **CASE-2**.
It's only giving me a popup saying 'This action not available for this item'.

I have to do this to maintain consistency in both case. So need solution from one of below..

1. If there is any way to enable both buttons in **CASE-2** (Like **CASE-1**)
2. If there is any way to disable both buttons in **CASE-1** (Like **CASE-2**)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code for this? It seems as though the logic for checking if multiple emails are selected is faulty.

Comment: @AndyWynn
You can see snippet of it. I have edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you disable the `Reply` and `Reply to All` actions on the first selected item which is a different item in both scenarios:

```
MailItem objMailItem = objSelectionList[1] as MailItem;
if (objMailItem != null)
{
   objMailItem.Actions["Reply"].Enabled = false;
   objMailItem.Actions["Reply to All"].Enabled = false;
}
```

But the displayed item is always the same, but it is not necessary the first in the collection. So, instead I'd suggest iterating over all selected items and disabling actions for all of them to make sure  the view is updated correctly. A raw sketch:

```
for(int i=1; i <= objSelectionList.Count; i++)
{
  MailItem objMailItem = objSelectionList[i] as MailItem;
  if (objMailItem != null)
  {
    objMailItem.Actions["Reply"].Enabled = false;
    objMailItem.Actions["Reply to All"].Enabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But objMailItem.Actions["Reply"].Enabled not disabling/grey-out a buttons as showing in CASE-2 screenshot. Its just giving me popup saying 'This action not available for this item'.

Comment: That is because the first item is not visible in the UI (`Test 1`). In case of failures you can handle exceptions to suppress them and try on another item.

Comment: Thanks for posting answer. This is issue from outlook side. Thanks.